# Question about a minorly used tag

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

There once were sixteen chairs.
Next to orthogonal.
There are people wearing only black or only white.

[REDACTED]

A black-wearer is in the corner.
A white-wearer is next to a black-wearer.
At least two white-wearers are next to corners.
All wearers are on the edges.
Only a few seats are full.
They’re a part of the Council of Five, and one is up speaking.
One column isn’t used.
I believe this narrows it down to only ONE proper configuration, of course, I may be wrong…

Where are our members sitting?

This is a meeting at Nikoli headquarters, by the way.

Comment: ONE MAJOR TAG IS MISSING (would ruin suspense)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the "Nikoli headquarters" and [grid-deduction](/questions/tagged/grid-deduction) tag, this is likely

> some puzzle involving black and white circles. And given the "council of 5" tag, there are likely only 5 total clues; the most likely such puzzle that could have a low clue density is a **Masyu.**

There are still many such solutions, though. Here are a few:

> [image: masyu 1] [image: masyu 2] [image: masyu 3]
>
>  Any reflection of the above would also work.

Comment: At least two white-wearers are next to corners?

Comment: If "one column is not used" means the, uhm, green part can't pass there either, there are fewer options (although still at least 2, I think).

Comment: @Amoz Yes, in my images, all three white-wearers are next to corners.

Comment: @Jafe Hm, if that's the correct interpretation, I don't see *any* "proper configurations" - there's no way to control the center well enough to prevent that column from being used.

Comment: I was thinking something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzqQS.png), although I may have missed something

Comment: Or maybe a better example is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnnww.png) which at least has a unique solution, unlike my above example?

Comment: @Jafe Ah, of course, you can use three black circles... that *is* a "proper" configuration, but it's definitely not the only one.

Comment: Maybe "one is up speaking" means that the top row should only have one circle? Even with *that*, you can still reflect the configuration, though.

Comment: @Jafe is right (at least one is, I added “only one column” for correct configuration)

Comment: Problem is though, there are only four. Most of it shouldn’t be implied.

Comment: @someoneinexistence I don't quite understand what you mean here, but I'm still having trouble figuring out what interpretation leads to the solution you believe is unique. I believe that if there are only 4 clues, there *isn't* a "proper" configuration fitting your requirements at all.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of what @Jafe said in his second answer. I was thinking IMPLIED top right black circle but that doesn’t have a unique answer. I should have added a perimeter constraint so the top right black circle in Jafe’s could have been implied…

Comment: I’ll just checkmark your answer and add an OP comments section with what I did wrong :(at least someone gets some rep out of my mistake :)